# URL Rewriter and dynamic page structure

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, url-rewriting

I'm working on a system that allows users to create and generate their own pages on the fly.

I am hooking this up with URL Rewriter so that I can access the pages via a single page that will be passed the page name / ID via a query string. That's the easy part as I know I can use:

```
<rewrite url="/(.+)/" to="/GenericPage.aspx?PageName=$1" />
```

Now comes the fun part. Users can also create folders that have sub pages and/or sub-folders. These folders can be n deep and there are no limits to their depth. I've mainly implemented this because the structure will generate a top nav with these folders being the top level menu options and sub folders and so on.

Is it possible for me to use a rewrite rule that will take in to account the rule that there could be a large number of folders before the page that I require? I don't want to create multiple rules as it just seems dirty and relying on there to be a maximum number of folders.

```
**What I'm trying to avoid**
<rewrite url="/(.+)/(.+)/" to="/GenericPage.aspx?PageName=$2" />
<rewrite url="/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/" to="/GenericPage.aspx?PageName=$3" />
<rewrite url="/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/" to="/GenericPage.aspx?PageName=$4" />
<rewrite url="/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/" to="/GenericPage.aspx?PageName=$5" />
<!-- Where the additional (.+) are representative of folders -->
```

I seem to have stumped myself with this one (maybe I'm a little tired today).

It would be perfect if there was a `take after 2nd last /` rule in URL Rewriter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have URL Rewriter installation to test with but the following regular expression probably can help:

```
.*/([^/]+?)/
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use aspx but, if you can, you may be better off using something like

```
<rewrite url=".?" to="/RoutingHandler.aspx" />
```

This bypasses URL rewriting by regex (and thus all potential parameter escaping issues) so that in `RoutingHandler.aspx` you access the original request's URL via the server variables. With that you can split virtual directories on forward-slashes into an array. You can map the array to parameters, pages in a database or whatever you want.

The `.?` is just the quickest match-every request regex. You may need adjust it so it doesn't hijack static content requests.